# I am unable to load Geoserver Dashboard

Tags: geoserver, installation, boundless-suite, mac

I have just installed the OpenGeoServer Suite from Boundless and when I go to open the dashboard @ http://localhost:8080/dashboard I get a 404 error not found.

edit: just realized that apache is installed on http://localhost:8080/, I have tried to uninstall it but no luck

Comment: Welcome @Dazzle :-) I have added an answer according to your own answer. I suggest you remove the answer from your question and then check for the correct answer. You should be able to edit my answer below if you have further details.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if an other service is running on the same port. Check if Apache or other services are running. Uninstall or stop those services and you should be fine.